# AMPScript loop to concat only non empty fields in a row

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop

I am trying to concat all the non empty field values from a row in my DE,  into a single variable (each value in the concatenated string separated by a comma).

The field names are: `FIELD1`, `FIELD2` and `FIELD3`. Hence I tried adding a counter `@i` to the field name in a loop, but no luck.

For example, if only `FIELD2` and `FIELD3` had values( '*abc*' and '*def*') and `FIELD1` was empty, my desired output would be:   *"abc,def"*

```
set @Id = 'test.gmail.com'
set @rows = LookupRows("MyDE","Id", @Id)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 
set @row = row(@rows,1)   
set @strng = ""

/* here is the loop where I try to concat the non empty values */

FOR @i = 1 TO 3 DO
  if not empty(field(@row,CONCAT("FIELD", @i))) then
      set @strng = field(@row,CONCAT("FIELD", @i, ','))
  else
  endif
NEXT @i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight change should get you there:

Basic Solution:

```
set @Id = 'test.gmail.com'
set @rows = LookupRows("MyDE","Id", @Id)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 
set @row = row(@rows,1)   

SET @Field1 = FIELD(@row,"Field1")
SET @Field2 = FIELD(@row,"Field2")
SET @Field3 = FIELD(@row,"Field3")

SET @strng = CONCAT(IIF(NOT EMPTY(@Field1), CONCAT(@Field1,","), ""), IIF(NOT EMPTY(@Field2), CONCAT(@Field2,","), ""), IIF(NOT EMPTY(@Field3), @Field3, ""))
]%%
```

Which if

```
Field 1 = '' 
Field 2 = 'not empty'
Field 3 = 'I have content'
```

Then @strng = `not empty,I have content`

Now if you have a high number of fields and require a for loop instead of manually writing each out, you could try:

```
set @Id = 'test.gmail.com'
set @rows = LookupRows("MyDE","Id", @Id)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 
set @row = row(@rows,1)   
set @strng = ""

FOR @i = 1 TO 3 DO
  set @tempTAC = TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%','%[ SET @tempVal = ', 'Field(@row, "Field',@i, '")', ']%', '%'))
  if not empty(@tempVal) then
      set @strng = IIF(EMPTY(@strng), @tempVal, CONCAT(@strng,',',@tempVal))
  endif
NEXT @i
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to expand it by for each iteration to do a lookup with `@tempVal` in another DE. And then concat that value to `@string`. Seems to work fine, except for the first iteration. Then it does not give me a value for the lookup.... 

This is my code:      
`set @tempTAC2= TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%','%[ SET @tempVal2 = ', 'Lookup("SecondDE","Title","Country", @tempVal)' , ']%', '%'))`.    

Then I add the var here:
`set @strng = IIF(EMPTY(@strng), @tempVal, CONCAT(@strng,',',@tempVal, @tempVal2 ))`.

Any idea what is going wrong here :) Thanks!

Comment: I bet its because in the CONCAT you need to have the `@tempVal` not be part of the 'string' but instead declared as the var and wrap it in double quotes (`"`). Like so: `set @tempTAC2= TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%','%[ SET @tempVal2 = Lookup("SecondDE","Title","Country","', @tempVal,'")]%', '%'))`

Comment: Thank again! But no luck Im afraid. What seems to do the trick is the following (still using my script). In the line where we create the 'string' I add `@tempVal2` in the `IF` statement: 

         
`set @strng = IIF(EMPTY(@strng), CONCAT(@tempVal, @tempVal2), CONCAT(@strng, ',' ,@tempVal, @tempVal2))`. 

So, when 'string' is empty then do `CONCAT(@tempVal, @tempVal2)`, rather than only `@tempVal`.

Comment: You are right, would need to be added to both. I was completely concentrating on the wrong part of your issue - thought `@tempVal2` was returning blank. Great work figuring it out!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! :)